# How hide or delete inline button after click?

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot

How hide or delete button after click it ?

```
function newQuestion(msg){
    if (count!==3) {
        var arr = questions[count];
        var text = arr.title;
        var options = {
            reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
                inline_keyboard: arr.buttons,
                parse_mode: 'Markdown',
            })
        };
        chat = msg.hasOwnProperty('chat') ? msg.chat.id : msg.from.id;
        bot.sendMessage(chat, text, options);
        countMap.set(msg.from.id,countMap.get(msg.from.id)+1);
    }
}
```

I've tried
`"hide_keyboard: true"`

But it didn't work.

Comment: What are you even using? You can hide buttons on a website, androind, ios etc. Where do you need to do this?

Comment: You do know aside from it been a bot, no one knows what framework you working on, and where the button apply , as when you say button we expect normal html button with id

Comment: it is just telegram bot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `editMessageReplyMarkup` method, and remains `reply_markup` as empty array like [this request](https://tg.sean.taipei/payload.php?editMessageReplyMarkup-c14e38e2).

Answer (score 0):

When you handle the callback message generated from the user's click on the button you must call the method `editMessageReplyMarkup` passing it the object

`{
    reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
       keyboard: []
}}`

Anyway it may depend on the api you are using. I am referring to node-telegram-bot-api which is documented [here](https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api/blob/release/doc/api.md#telegramboteditmessagereplymarkupreplymarkup-options--promise)