# Telegram bot: editMessageReplyMarkup method doesn't work

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot, inline, node-telegram-bot-api

I've developed a telegram bot using Node.js and node-telegram-bot-api module that sends a message and an inline keyboard to the users, what I'm trying is to achieve that after the user clicks the button, the inline keyboard must disappear. I'm using `editMessageReplyMarkup` but it gives the mentioned errors

Reference: [Method editMessageReplyMarkup removes inline keybord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54562560/method-editmessagereplymarkup-removes-inline-keybord)

Part of code:

```
bot.on('callback_query', function onCallbackQuery(example) {
    const action = example.data 
    const msg_id = example.message.from.id
    const chat_id = example.from.id

    //console.log(example.from.id)

    if (action == 'FM') {
        
        bot.editMessageReplyMarkup({
            reply_markup: {


                inline_keyboard: [
                    [
                       
                    ],

                ]
            }
        }, {
            chat_id: chat_id,
            message_id: msg_id
        });
    }
  });
```

Error:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: ETELEGRAM: 400 Bad Request: message to edit not found
```

I've tried the following solution as well but it doesn't work

Reference:
[How hide or delete inline button after click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48148915/how-hide-or-delete-inline-button-after-click)

```
bot.on('callback_query', function onCallbackQuery(example) {
    const action = example.data 
    const msg_id = example.message.from.id
    const chat_id = example.from.id

    console.log(example.from.id)

    if (action == 'FM') {
        console.log(action)
        console.log("FM")
        console.log(msg_id)
        // console.log(example.message.message_id)

        bot.editMessageReplyMarkup({
            chat_id: chat_id,
            message_id: msg_id,
            reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
                keyboard: []
            })
        }

        );
    }


});
```

Error:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: ETELEGRAM: 400 Bad Request: message identifier is not specified
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're referring to wrong msg_id.
It should be

```
const msg_id = example.message.message_id
bot.editMessageReplyMarkup({
            reply_markup: {


                inline_keyboard: [
                    [

                    ],

                ]
            }
        }, {
            chat_id: chat_id,
            message_id: msg_id
        });
```

execute `console.log(example)` to get a clear idea of the response

Answer (score 0):

Use this order parameters
bot.telegram.editMessageReplyMarkup(chatId, messageId, newMarkup);